# Searchview needs extra onBackPressed

Tags: android, fragment, searchview

I was trying to resolve that problem almost a week, but I still have no idea why this is happening. I have a Searchview with OnQueryTextListener():

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if(newText.length()==0) {
        if(!(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.routesFragment) instanceof Fragment_Search)) {
            fragment_search = new Fragment_Search();
            replaceFragment(fragment_search);
        }
    }

    if (newText.length()>0){
        final DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        databaseAccess.open();
        ArrayList<Route_Common> list = databaseAccess.searchInDB(newText);
        databaseAccess.close();
        fragment_search.listChanged(list);
    }

    return false;
}
```

So, when searchview is expanded I replace current fragment with a special Search_fragment.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!searchView.isIconified()) {
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        onBackPressed();
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
    drawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
}
```

But if I want to hide my searchview and go back to my previous fragment, I need to press it twice - first time to collapse it, and second - to go back. I tried *searchView.clearFocus()* programmatically and call *onBackPressed()* twice inside  **if (!searchView.isIconified())**, but it still doesn't work. Maybe it's a really dumb question, but I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. I just added

```
searchView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
   @Override
   public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
       Log.d("MyTag","Search Expanded");
       fragment_search = new Fragment_Search();
        replaceFragment(fragment_search);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
        Log.d("MyTag","Search Hide");
        onBackPressed();
        }
});
```